# Integral Evaluation Trouble

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I have the following indefinite integral:
$$\int\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1+2x}dx$$

I was thinking substitution, so let $u=1+2x$.  then $du=2dx$ and thus
$$\int\frac{e^{\frac{u-1}{2}}}{e^{u-1}+u}du$$

I've haven't done integration in quite sometime and was checking over my old calculus book for either identities or techniques and am coming up blank.  I would also be looking for the definite integral
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1+2x}dx$$
I have a feeling I need complex analysis. I haven't done it in a while and we never covered integration in my intro course.

EDIT:  I changed the bounds of the definite integral from 0 to 1 into 0 to infinity

Comment: Honestly I doubt whether a closed form exists.

Comment: i think a solution in the elementary functions exists not

Comment: This is the [W|A result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}%2B1%2B2x}dx).

Comment: this is not a proof but you can study the Rish-algorithm

Comment: With limits $-\infty,\infty$ or $0,\infty$  the integrals could be expressed by the help of Residue theorem and Lamebert's W-function

Comment: If I change the bounds from 0 to $\infty$ could you show me how to use the above mentioned theorem/function?